# Model.find is not working with mongoid

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I am not able find the record using Model.find(id).

```
Food.find('548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6') => Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
```

But when I try find the same record using column name , I will return same record.

```
 Food.where({name:"Aloo Matar" }).first
 => #<Food _id: 548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6, rawOrPrepared: "P", name: "Aloo Matar", tags: "vegetable", alternateNames: "potatoes">
```

For my case, find works differently based on string. Please see the below code.

```
  Food.where({_id: "zyCMnbTPENeXkhawT" })
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>"zyCMnbTPENeXkhawT"}
  options:  {}
  class:    Food
  embedded: false>

2.2.1 :017 > Food.where({_id: '548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6' })
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6')}
  options:  {}
  class:    Food
  embedded: false>
```

But first code returns the object while second code raise the exception.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Hare

Comment: Is the `_id` a string that looks like a `BSON::ObjectId` or a real `BSON::ObjectId`? What does `db.foods.findOne({ _id: '548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6' })` say from the `mongodb` CLI tool? How about `db.foods.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6') })`?

Comment: from mongo console, i am able to find the data. Please see the below code from mongo client.

db.foods.find({_id: "548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6"})
{ "_id" : "548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6",  "manufacturer" : "homemade", "modified" : "2014-12-10T06:47:56.275Z", "name" : "Aloo Matar"}
> 
> db.foods.find({_id: "zyCMnbTPENeXkhawT"})
{ "_id" : "zyCMnbTPENeXkhawT", "name" : "Recipe_281015072818", "tags" : "recipe", "manufacturer" : "homemade", "alternateNames" : "Brown Rice and Carrots", "modified" : "2015-10-28T07:28:20.542Z" }

Comment: I can get these data from mongodb client.

Comment: So your `_id` values are strings and sometimes those strings look like ObjectIds?

Comment: _id values are string.

Comment: Have you tried adding `field :_id, type: String` to your model? Having `_id`s that are strings but actually look like `BSON::ObjectId`s could be a problem though, Mongoid might keep trying to convert them to `ObjectId`s behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has happened because the document with `_id` equal to `548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6` was saved before you changed your model saying the `_id` field should have string type.

I suppose you inserted something like the below code onto your model after inserting that document on DB. Right?

```
field :_id, type: String, overwrite: true
```

**So... what is happening with document with id `548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6`?**

Simple. The document was saved with default mongodb `_id` type - which is `ObjectId`.

Now (after defining `_id` type as string) whenever you query DB with `548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6`, it will try to find a document with id equal to `548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6` but it won't find because it was stored as `ObjectId('548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6')`.

If you remove `field :_id, type: String, overwrite: true` from your model, you'll see that the document `548210e8d5a81037af06b2d6` will be found again, whilest `zyCMnbTPENeXkhawT` won't.

Thus to solve your problem you have to convert every id on mongodb to the same type.